# Read all the name and value pair in a section

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a config file with two section like this:

```
[Test]
sample1=abc
test1=123
test2=xxx

[Test2]
sample2=abc
test2=123
test2=xxx
```

I am using config parser to read each name and value. But the problem is this list is dynamic and will not be the same 'sample1', 'test1','test2' all the time.

So, for the current section, my output would be 
`test-string=abc, 123, xxx` 
`test-string2=abc, 123, xxx` 
If two new values are added to this Test section as xyz and 456, then my output would be 
`test-string=abc, 123, xxx, xyz, 456`.
`test-string2=abc, 123, xxx`

This file will have more section in the future and I want to do the same for each section.

Is there any other option apart from configparser to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You mean something like `line.split('=')`?

Comment: Not really. I want to get the values of all names in each section, irrespective of what the name is; Finally I want to do a string operation on it. I have updated my question to reflect this. Can you please check?

Comment: I think by "dynamic", he means that he wants to update the list of key-value pairs created in his program at runtime as the file content changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I'm guessing it's that your file will look like

```
[Section1]
somekey=val
anotherkey=val
wedontknowthesekeys=val
...
```

And you need to get the `key,value` pairs, without actually knowing what the keys might be. This isn't hard.

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('path/to/config.ini')

sections = config.sections()  # does not include defaults!
for section in sections:
    items = config.items(section)
    # items == [("somekey", "val"),
    #           ("anotherkey", "val"),
    #           ("wedontknowthesekeys", "val"),
    #           ...]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This smells like a typical input for a dictionary.  Let's assume that you've already read in the line as a string, such as "sample=abc".  Now ...

```
ref_dict = {}
for line in my_file:
    key, value = line.split('=')
    ref_dict[key] = value

print ref_dict
```

Comment: Hi, will this work if the list is dynamic? I will not know the contents of each section. And for each section I need to do a separate string operation . I have updated my question to reflect this. Can you please check? Thanks!

Comment: "Will this work" depends on the input and output desired.  No, this doesn't directly emit the desired output.  This is only a basic parse and store.  We've given you some basic approaches and specific techniques; we're not a coding service.  It's your turn to write code.  If you get stuck, post again with your actual code and the error or output you got.  Do a few lines at a time, and print intermediate values as you go.